# SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services Matrix Total Data Highlighting

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, reporting

I have created a SQL Server 2005 matrix with a total column.

I want to be able to change the colors of the totals only so they stand out from the rest of the data.     I can change the color of the "total" label, but not the actual data.

Can anyone give me a clue of how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test whether or not a cell is a total or not, you need to use the InScope() Function along with a heavily nested If statement. Jorg Klein does a great job of exlplaing how this works within a matrix ([here](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/jorg/archive/2007/12/06/SSRS-_2D00_-Custom-expressions-for-subtotals-in-a-matrix.aspx))

Answer (score 1):

Select the Total box and you can set the color in the properties page. If you want all totals to appear in the same color, this will do.

You can also conditionally format them, by putting an expression in the color property.

Check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156400.aspx)

Raj

Comment: That doesn't work in a matrix.  It only really works for tables.

Comment: Row number gets all confused in a matrix.  How would you know where to color the totals?

Comment: Did you check the link I posted? You will have to go for conditional formatting. Check to see if the cell is Total and color it differently. I have a report of scheduled jobs, a matrix, where the value is displayed in RED if the last run outcome is "Failed"

Comment: Yes, I checked the link.

How do you determine if the cell is a Total cell?   I think that is my problem.   Conditional formatting is relatively easy.  Determining the nature of the cell is the hard part.

Comment: How do you get the Total? Is that precalculated in the dataset or is it calculated in the report? Either way, there will always be a way to find out if a given cell is a total or not. Any possiblity of posting your report here?

Comment: I have found the answer.   You can use the InScope to determine if this is a total field.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken, you can select the totals cell for editing it's properties by selecting the cell and then clicking on the small triangle in the upper corner of the cell.

Hope this helps,

Bill